# Creating a query in Oracle to replace variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I've the following query:

```
SELECT c.accountid, c.accountnum
FROM account o, account@oltp c
WHERE o.accountid = c.accountid and c.date > sysdate;
```

I'm logged in o datacenter' database and pulling details from c datacenter's database, and I need a simple PL/SQL query as follows:

```
declare
variable

begin
statements...
....

end
```

**I do not want any procedures or functions.**

All I want to do, is to replace: `account@oltp c` and `sysdate` as variables.

```
select c.accountid, c.accountnum
from account o, (variable)
where o.accountid = c.accountid and c.date > (variable);
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts ( accountid, accountnum ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 11;

CREATE TABLE accounts2 ( accountid, accountnum, "date" ) AS
  SELECT 2*LEVEL, 2*LEVEL, SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 6;
```

**PL/SQL Anonymous Block**:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; 
/
DECLARE
  TYPE acc_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
  table_name  VARCHAR2(100) := 'accounts2';
  datetime    DATE          := SYSDATE;
  v_cursor    acc_cursor;
  v_accid     NUMBER;
  v_accnum    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR
    'SELECT c.accountid, c.accountnum '
     || 'FROM   accounts o '
     || 'INNER JOIN ' || table_name || ' c '
     || 'ON ( o.accountid = c.accountid ) '
     || 'WHERE c."date" > :dt'
  USING datetime;

  -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_accid, v_accnum;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_accid || ' - ' || v_accnum );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
/
```